# Migration Lightning, can't deploy Utility Bar

Tags: lightning-apps, salesforce-classic

While migrating an org from Classic to Lightning,
I'm trying to deploy and add a Utility Bar ;
I'm using Workbenchn, following [this official document,](https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/utility_bar_impl_guide.pdf)
I'm facing this error message when deploying the Utility Bar :

[image: problem: UtilityBar isn't supported for Salesforce Classic apps.]

The xml of the app I wan't to add the bar in is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <defaultLandingTab>standard-home</defaultLandingTab>
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    <label>Air Force 1</label>
    <tab>standard-Account</tab>
    <tab>standard-Contact</tab>
    <tab>Produits__c</tab>
    <tab>Groupe_de_Produits__c</tab>
    <tab>Strates__c</tab>
    <tab>Objectif__c</tab>
    <tab>Calendrier_Promo</tab>
    <tab>Campagne_Promo__c</tab>
    <tab>Tablet_Config__c</tab>
    <tab>Secteur__c</tab>
    <tab>Zone_de_chalandise__c</tab>
    <tab>Temps_Fort__c</tab>
    <tab>Marque__c</tab>
    <tab>Promotion_Pirate__c</tab>
    <tab>Repartition_Automatique__c</tab>
    <tab>Releve_promo_pirate__c</tab>
    <tab>TabletLog__c</tab>
    <tab>standard-report</tab>
    <tab>WS_Erreur_Log__c</tab>
    <utilityBar>homePageUtilityBar</utilityBar>
</CustomApplication>
```

(I just added `<utilityBar>homePageUtilityBar</utilityBar>` )

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, tried two times being careful to do it step by step ...

Any help would be appreciated, it's my first migration.
Thanks!

Comment: is `Air_Force` app a classic salesforce app?

Comment: Yes it is, it's the one I want to migrate to Lightning... Ow. I see, I edited the wrong one ?! sorry, I'll try editing the xml of the adaptation, MY BAD

Comment: Ok, first I had to Upgrade the Classic App : App Manager > Select the App > Upgrade ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the error depicts, you cannot add utility components to the `Classic Salesforce` app,
to be able to do this, you need to have a `Lightning Experience` version of the app.

Comment: Yeap, I Uploaded the App to get a Ltng version, now I got another issue : my Utility Bar get deployed (success statut + Id generated) and I can add it to the Xml of the app, then deploy it successfully, but the custom utility bar doesn't seem to appear...
I'll open a new case for this, different issue from my first !
Thanks