# Lightning App - My Utility bar doesn't show

Tags: lightning-apps, xml, utility-bar

This topic continues [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284694/migration-lightning-cant-deploy-utility-bar/284706#284706) from yesterday, the context remains :

While migrating an org from Classic to Lightning, I'm trying to deploy and add a Utility Bar ; I'm using Workbenchn, following [this official document](https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/utility_bar_impl_guide.pdf)

The issue now is that my lightning App (called Air_Force_1_Lightning) with my Utility Bar (called AirForce1homeUtility).
The issue is the Utility Bar doesn't appear on the app homePage.

This is the AirForce1homeUtility JSon :

```
{
"FullName": "AirForce1homeUtility",
"Metadata": {
    "masterLabel": "Home Page Utility bar",
    "pageTemplate": "one:utilityBarTemplateDesktop",
    "type": "UtilityBar",
    "description": "This utility bar displays the Home Page Utility bar as in Classic Version - Usefull for Migration.",
    "flexiPageRegions": [
        {
            "appendable": null,
            "name": "utilityItems",
            "type": "Region",
            "componentInstances": [
                {
                    "componentName": "flexipage:recentItems",
                    "componentInstanceProperties": [
                        {
                            "name": "entityNames",
                            "value": "['Account']"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "maxRecords",
                            "value": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "label",
                            "type": "decorator",
                            "value": "Home Page Utility bar."
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "width",
                            "type": "decorator",
                            "value": "425"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "height",
                            "type": "decorator",
                            "value": "320"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Using Workbench to retrieve all FlexiPages, I can see AirForce1homeUtility :

[image]

And the App :
[image]

The App Xml includes AirForce1homeUtility, as a utilityBar :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    <label>Air Force 1 Lightning</label>
    <navType>Standard</navType>
    <tab>standard-home</tab>
    <tab>standard-Account</tab>
    <tab>standard-Contact</tab>
    <tab>Produits__c</tab>
    <tab>Groupe_de_Produits__c</tab>
    <tab>Strates__c</tab>
    <tab>Objectif__c</tab>
    <tab>Calendrier_Promo</tab>
    <tab>Campagne_Promo__c</tab>
    <tab>Tablet_Config__c</tab>
    <tab>Secteur__c</tab>
    <tab>Zone_de_chalandise__c</tab>
    <tab>Temps_Fort__c</tab>
    <tab>Marque__c</tab>
    <tab>Promotion_Pirate__c</tab>
    <tab>Repartition_Automatique__c</tab>
    <tab>Releve_promo_pirate__c</tab>
    <tab>TabletLog__c</tab>
    <tab>standard-report</tab>
    <tab>WS_Erreur_Log__c</tab>
    <uiType>Lightning</uiType>
    <utilityBar>Air_Force_1_Lightning_UtilityBar</utilityBar>
</CustomApplication>
```

Still, the App shoes components I want but not the UtilityBar :

[image]

EDIT : a screenshot of the items I can as Utility Items

[image]

Comment: What does it look like when you go to edit the custom app in the UI and select "utility items? Can you add the item you're looking for? It might just be a deployment issue.

Comment: No, I can not !
I edited my post with a screenshot

Comment: Is AirForce1homeUtility an aura component? Is it using flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes interface?

Comment: It's a flexiPage with those attributes :

"pageTemplate": "one:utilityBarTemplateDesktop",
"type": "UtilityBar"

Comment: @AlexisMASSON can  you also show the content of package.xml